# By using Syncfusion.XlsIO in c# to export excel file to json is there any way to define header cell that contain a space?

Tags: c#, json, excel, export, syncfusion

I'm using Syncfusion.XlsIO in c# to easily export excel file sheet and I'm using the tutorial [Export Excel data to JSON format in C#, VB.NET](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9095/export-excel-data-to-json-format-in-c-vb-net).

The example works when the Sample.xlnx file for example looks like the following:

| `CustomerID` | `CustomerName` |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Alex |

But my excel file Sample.xlnx looks like the following:

| `Customer ID` | `Customer Name` |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Alex |

The question is how could I define the header name when the header contains a  space?

If I make it with space the result is null for the name and 0 for id.

The model class `Customer` is the following:

```
class Customer
{
    #region Members
    private int m_CustomerID;
    private string m_CustomerName;

    #endregion

    #region Prperties
    [DisplayNameAttribute("CustomerID CustomerName")]
    public int CustomerID
    {
        get
        {
            return m_CustomerID;
        }
        set
        {
            m_CustomerID = value;
        }
    }

    public string CustomerName
    {
        get
        {
            return m_CustomerName;
        }
        set
        {
            m_CustomerName = value;
        }
    }
  
    #endregion

    #region Intialization
    public Customer()
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Sorry it's *json in the Title

Answer (score 0):

You have a different name in the *DisplayNameAttribute*. It should be defined for each property as shown in the code below.

```
#region Properties
[DisplayNameAttribute("Customer ID")]
public int CustomerID
{
    get
    {
        return m_customerID;
    }
    set
    {
        m_customerID = value;
    }
}

[DisplayNameAttribute("Customer Name")]
public string CustomerName
{
    get
    {
        return m_customerName;
    }
    set
    {
        m_customerName = value;
    }
}
```

Now Excel to JSON will be a built-in feature in the upcoming version 18.2, which is expected to be rolled out in the first week of July 2020. You can also try with that.

**Note:** I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion is glad to say that Excel to JSON is now available as a built-in feature in the release version 18.2. You can try the same with the help of the following KB document.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9095/export-excel-data-to-json-format-in-c-vb-net

**Note:** I work for Syncfusion.